# Clicking to next page on casperjs not working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to take a screenshot of the second page on a website that uses ajax, using casperjs.
I used Chrome and Ressurectio to create a test script and changed it slightly in order to suit my needs.

However, when I run the script, the second screenshot only shows the "loading" page, which at first I thought it's due to ajax being slow...

The problem is that even with a timeout of 15 seconds, it still doesn't take the screenshot that I want.

Maybe I'm forgetting something?

Here's my script:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 667};
casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
   this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
   for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
       var step = trace[i];
       this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
   }
});
casper.test.begin('Resurrectio test', function(test) {
   casper.start('http://recrutamento.auchan.pt/listaofertas.aspx');

   casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='>>>']"),
       function success() {
            this.capture('click1.png')
            test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='>>>']"));
            this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='>>>']"));
            this.wait(7000);
            this.capture('click2.png')
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='>>>']"));
   });

   casper.run(function() {test.done();});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` is an asynchronous step function such as `then`, so you have to put `capture` into the callback of `wait`:

```
this.wait(7000, function(){
    this.capture('click2.png')
});
```

You're taking the screenshot to early.

Comment: All `wait*` functions are asynchronous. There is no `sleep` function in JavaScript, so when you want to wait, you have to use `setTimeout` behind the scenes which is asynchronous.